# How to make Active a View inside Multiview in Clientside Javascript in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have three views inside a Multiview 
How to activate one by one view means I Just want to change the Active View Index of the Multiview using javascript in ClientSide How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you will be able to without causing a post back as the multiview is a server side control and only the active view is rendered to the browser.

You probably need to have all the views on the page and all but one hidden. Are you implementing some time of tab control?

There is a tab control in the ajax control toolkit which switches between views clientside:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx